# Проверить создано ли уведомление с заданным id

Tags: android, java

Подскажите как можно проверить создано ли уведомление с заданным id?

Создаю напоминание следующим образом:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentInten...
Notification n = builder.getNotification();
nm.notify(id, n);
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это невозможно. Единственное, что вы можете сделать это отслеживать врукопашную при создании нотификации и как то узнавать когда он убрано.

Я в свое время занимался - безуспешно.

Comment: Видимо никак не узнать, что уведомление убрано? Или как-то можно это событие отловить?(Интересно знать, что б продолжать копать в эту сторону или искать другое решение проблемы)

Comment: @Мария_1, да совершенно верно - никак не узнать убрано уведомление или нет. В качестве варианта можно самому врукопашную убирать (чтобы быть точно уверенным что уведомление убрано) - мне помог такой подход

Comment: @Мария_1 Есть еще вариант передавать активити стартующей из нотификации спец. экшн параметр и с помощью этого параметра детектировать момент нажатия юзером на нотификацию (ну и соответственно деактивации). Есть еще вариант повесить бродкаст на нотификацию - [посмотрите сюда](http://hashcode.ru/questions/311156/java-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-custom-notification)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦
Момент нажатия ловлю, открывая при этом активити. Осталось поймать момент закрытия)

Comment: @Мария_1 дык, если нотификация создана как `autocancel` то открытие активити равнозначно закрытию, не?

Comment: @Barmaley ♦
А если пользователь убрал напоминание, не открывая при этом активити? Очистил,либо сдвинув в бок

Comment: @Мария_1 тогда ой...